# Determining a set that's a countably infinite union, its boundary and derived set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to find $E$, $\delta E$ and $E'$ given a set $E$ that's a union of sets $E_n, n > 0$, each defined as:

$E_n = \{(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}$$:1+\frac{1}{n}\leq\ x^2+y^2\leq 2+\frac{1}{n}\}$.

I know that $E = \bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}_+} \! E_n$, but I can't understand how to compute it.

The boundary and derived sets will be pretty easy to find once I determine what $E$ is.

Comment: Hint: Think about circles with radius $r$. Then $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, which gives you $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \leq r \leq \sqrt{2 + \frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: I forgot to write that I have drawn the picture of the set and I have found that $E_n$ is an annulus between the two circles of radius $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: Yes, each is an annulus. There's an even easier way to write the condition defining $E_1$. Now look at $E_2$: where does its outer circle fall? what's the inner circle? For any $n$, where does the outer circle of $E_n$ fall, and what's it's inner circle? Is there any point that's inside every inner circle (not in any annulus)?

Comment: @BrianO So, if I analyze the range in between the radius of the two circles can move, I obtain my answer. I found that the radius of the outer circle has its max value at $\sqrt{3}$, while the inner circle has its max value at $\sqrt{2}$. The min values, on the other hand, are $1$ for the inner circle and  $\sqrt{2}$ for the outer one. 
Should I take the smallest value for the inner and the greatest value for the outer circle to get my answer?

Comment: Yes. Of course you're right about the outer radius of $E_1$. Where does the outer radius of any $E_n$ fall? What's the relationship between the inner radii as $n$ increases - what do they approach?

Comment: @BrianO As I wrote above, as $n$ increases the inner radius converges to $1$

Comment: Right, but careful -- it's not really "min", it's $inf$ -- they tend toward but never actually achieve that value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was imprecise: what i called "min value" are indeed the limits to which the radius tend as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that
$$E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : 1< x^2+y^2 \leqslant 3 \right\}, $$
as if $(x,y)\in E_n$ for some $n$, then $1<1+\frac1n\leqslant x^2+y^2\leqslant2+\frac1n\leqslant 3$ and if $1<x^2+y^2\leqslant3$ then $1+\frac1n\leqslant x^2+y^2\leqslant 1+\frac1n$ for some $n$. It follows that
$$E^c = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2\leqslant 1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2>3\},$$
and so $$\partial E = \overline E\cap\overline{E^c} = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=3\}. $$

Comment: That's what I was dancing around in my comments :)